# CPAN install to many directories

Tags: linux, debian, perl, debian-lenny, cpan

When I install stuff locally (not as root) with CPAN, it ends up putting things in a multitude of places.  So much so, that I have to set PERL5LIB to five directories!

Here's the CPAN settings where I tell it where to install to:

```
  'makepl_arg' => q[PREFIX=/home/user],
  'mbuildpl_arg' => q[--install_base /home/user],
```

Here's what I have to set PERL5LIB to:

```
/home/user/lib/perl:/home/user/lib/perl5:/home/user/lib/perl/5.10:/home/user/share/perl:/home/user/share/perl/5.10
```

There must be a cleaner way...  I could symlink them all to the same place, but that just seems wrong.

This is on a debian lenny system running perl from debian squeeze.

Answer (score 1):

Either [`local::lib`](http://search.cpan.org/~apeiron/local-lib-1.008004/lib/local/lib.pm) or [`Perlbrew`](http://perlbrew.pl) (or [both](http://blogs.perl.org/users/chisel/2010/10/locallib-and-perlbrew.html)) should be able to simplify things for you. Even more importantly, don't use `CPAN` to install modules; use [`cpanm`](https://github.com/miyagawa/cpanminus).

My preference is simply to use Perlbrew to install non-system Perl interpreters in my `$HOME` directory. After that, each interpreter is self-contained and `cpanm` takes care of modules. Honestly, I never need to think about where modules end up. It just works.

Comment: I'll take a look at those, but I don't want to install a perl interpreter, as /home is on a networked file system (with a quota), and for performance reasons, I'd like to use as much from /usr as I can.

Comment: @Jayen With a set-up like that, I understand not wanting to install a new Perl interpreter. `local::lib` and `cpanm` should be able to simplify your modules, though, even without Perlbrew.